# symfony form setting compound attributes

Tags: forms, symfony

I need to set a couple of attributes on form elements for client side validation.
I can do this from an extension easily in the `buildView` method for simple form elements, but run into problems with radio-buttons for example.

The value would be the same for each `<input type="radio"...` and the value is dependent on the id of the compound element (not to be confused with the id of the separate input elements).

I noticed the `buildView` method is run for each input-type-radio, but I can't figure out where to get the correct id from.

How can I set this in a simple way?
Preferably from the Extension class itself and in a generic way.

It also needs to work on all other input elements in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any way to do this in the Extension class.

I did manage to get it done in a twig template though, but it is not really a nice solution". Since I only really needed it for radio buttons, I could add some logic in the form twig block `choice_widget_expanded`:

```
{{- form_widget(child, { 'attr': { 'my-attribute-name': 'my-value') } }) -}}
{{- form_widget(child, { 'attr': { 'my-attribute-name': attribute(attr, 'from-main-radio-form-element') } }) -}}
```

Use the second line to copy an attribute from the compound form element.